# Making a RESTful call to Amazon Web service using Power-shell

Tags: rest, powershell, amazon-web-services

I am trying to collect data from amazon web services. Every time I make the call I get back a 403 Forbidden.

This is what my code looks like (the link is jumbled):

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://hosted-data-work.s3.amazonaws.com/20161121T220310.324/dw_split/73610000000000001/assignment_fact/part00101.gzAWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJVX3JXfd5dfdfRKJNGM74Q&Expires=1479839499&Signature=J4JdyX53AwH6wExVmoVAtkweCEI%3D&resp222onse-contentdisposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22assignment_fact-00000-095582fd.gz%22%3B&x-amz-security-token=bluh" -Method Get

The link above is a download file. I just want to get the data the simplest way possible. What else do I need to add in the call? I have no clue about aws!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/powershell

Comment: What specific task are you trying to accomplish? Try asking the question in more of a task-oriented manner, and perhaps we'll be able to help you. As @AnthonyNeace has pointed out, you might want to start by working with the AWS PowerShell module, rather than calling REST APIs directly.

Comment: the link is a file download. I just want to download it in the simplest way possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misinformed and took a bad approach at this problem. I did not know I can simply download the file to my computer. I though it had to be transferred from bucket to bucket, then to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

How did you generate that URL? It looks like a presigned URL, which means the authorization for accessing the object will be granted based on the credentials used when presigning. There are a couple of possible reasons that could be giving you a not authorized response:

1. The credentials used to generate the presigned URL do not actually have permissions to read the object. Double check your IAM policies and/or ACLs for the bucket and the IAM user which generated the URL.
2. The signature got truncated/corrupted between the the time you generated the presigned URL and the time you tried to use it. Try logging the url when you generate it and again when you use it and compare to make sure they match exactly.
3. Presigned URLs expire after a specified validity period which cannot be longer than 1 week. Make sure you are generating a fresh URL when needed and setting the expiration appropriately.

Any of those could be causing the result you're seeing.